# safely specifying 'order by' clause from user input in python / postgresql / psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

i feel like this is a stupid question but i can't find anything anywhere.

I want to build an SQL query using psycopg2 where the user specifies the sort / order by column.. client-side its a javascript grid of data offering sorting / paging etc.

normal substitution practice doesn't work: (note the E'xx')

```
cur.mogrify('select * from table offset %s limit %s order by %s', [0,5,'sort_column'])
>>> "select * from table offset 0 limit 5 order by E'sort_column'"
```

short of cleansing / substituting the order by clause in myself, what is the recommended way to do this ?

am i a duplicate of:
[psycopg2 E' on table, field and schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294001/psycopg2-e-on-table-field-and-schema)
?

cheers

-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity names (tables/columns etc...) in Python's DBAPI shouldn't be run through any place holder processing as variables are supposed to be. You will have to do your own formatting:

```
'select * from table offset %s limit %s order by %s' % (0,5,'sort_column')
```

But do use the proper escaping/placeholder functions for `WHERE var = %s` etc...

Comment: ok thanks.. if that's the way it is then that's the way it is.