# Using python and postgres, variables within execute function?

Tags: python, string, postgresql, parameters, psycopg2

I had a question regarding the usage of variables inside a python function which accesses the PostgreSQL server. For example, the following:

```
def delete():
    cur.execute(
    """DELETE FROM potluck 
    WHERE name = var_1;"""
```

However, If I wanted the update function to take in variables for var_1, how would I do so?

For example, I want my function to be in the form:

```
def delete(var_1):
    cur.execute(
    """DELETE FROM potluck 
    WHERE name = %s;""", (var_1))
```

However, just typing that didn't work.

In addition, how about in the case when:

```
def delete(name, var_1):
    cur.execute(
    """DELETE FROM potluck 
    WHERE %s = %s;""", (name, var_1))
```

where I don't want "name" to have quotation marks when it is inserted into the string?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Normally table structures are something fixed. Dynamic tables are a design error most of the times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793399/passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-psycopg2

Comment: Definitely a duplicate!

Comment: Same problem? Yes. Duplicate? No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

I see what I was doing wrong. The only change I needed to make was add a comma after var_1, since:
 "For positional variables binding, the second argument must always be a sequence, even if it contains a single variable. And remember that Python requires a comma to create a single element tuple".

For example:

```
def delete(var_1):
    cur.execute(
    """DELETE FROM potluck 
    WHERE name = %s;""", (var_1,))
```

This works. I got the info from:

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#sql-injection

In the second case, then please reference the other answer below, which uses AsIs. That works. For example:

```
def delete(name, var_1):
    cur.execute(
    """DELETE FROM potluck 
    WHERE %s = %s;""", (AsIs(name), var_1))
```

That does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To pass identifiers use `psycopg2.extensions.AsIs`

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

def update(table_name, var_1, var_2):
    cur.execute("""
        UPDATE %s
        SET %s = 'Y'
        WHERE %s = 'John';
        """,
        (AsIs(table_name), AsIs(var_1), AsIs(var_2))
    )
```

Comment: sorry, I changed the question drastically since you answered, so I apologize for wasting your time. However, I did figure out the answer! Thanks!