# psycopg2 interpolate table name in executemany statement

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data into a table.  The table is determined in the beging of the program and remains constant throughout.  How do I interpolate the table name in an execute many statement like the one below?

```
tbl = 'table_name'
rows = [{'this':x, 'that': x+1} for x in range(10)]
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO %(tbl)s 
                  VALUES(
                          %(this)s,
                          %(that)s
                  )""", rows)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793399/passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-psycopg2

Comment: So, the table name cannot be interpolated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793399/passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-psycopg2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the official documentation: "Only query values should be bound via this method: it shouldn’t be used to merge table or field names to the query. If you need to generate dynamically an SQL query (for instance choosing dynamically a table name) you can use the facilities provided by the psycopg2.sql module."

It has the following syntax:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
tbl = 'table_name'
rows = [{'this':x, 'that': x+1} for x in range(10)]
cur.execute(
    sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%(this)s, %(that)s);"""")
        .format(sql.Identifier(tbl)), rows)
```

More on http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql