# Django raw sql format tablename

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to interpolate the tablename into a raw sql but it's interpolating a badly formatted string so the SQL query fails. I can't find a proper way of interpolating the string into the SQL query properyly:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from %s;", ['product'])
```

Throws:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'product'"
LINE 1: SELECT * from 'product';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass table nor column names as parameter arguments. Instead do something like:

```
qry = "SELECT * from %s;" % 'product'
cursor.execute(qry)
```

While being mindful of the possibility of [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Comment: Ah great, and just for the record the query was `select %s from %s`. So it needs to be interpolated in 2 stages: `qry % ('%s', 'product')`

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah I figure you didn't want `select *`

Comment: Why not just [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947632/52499) the table name in place of being mindful?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza      How would I do this if I want a query like this: "SELECT * from %s WHERE group_id = %s;",[assembly_id, group_id]?