# psycopg2 Programming Error when using .format()

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.5, psycopg2, string.format

Im not sure exactly whats happening here but it might have something to do with format in python.
 Running this causes an error.

```
x = '00000201000012EB'
sql = """ SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {} """.format(x)
conn.execute(sql)
```

I get an error saying: syntax error near "EB"

however when i run the command like this:

```
sql = """ SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '00000201000012EB' """
conn.execute(sql)
```

It works fine.

Is there something wrong with the way im formatting this sql statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the variable as an argument to `execute()`:

```
cur.execute(""" SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = %s """, (x,))
```

If you are determined to use `format()`, you should add single quotes around the placeholder:

```
sql = """ SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = '{}' """.format(x)
```

Comment: i like it! The reason i'm using .format is because the input changes, i was just doing this as a simpler example. excellent answer sir

Comment: The two options are somehow similar, but generally `execute()` with arguments is a bit safer in context of potential SQL injection. See e.g. [psycopg2 and SQL injection security.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128973/1995738)

Comment: I don't know much about SQL injection, but if you say the first option is safer, i'll make the changes to my code =)

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not it was fixed by adding more quotes to the string.

this finally worked.

```
x = '00000201000012EB'
sql = """ SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {} """.format("'" + x + "'")
```

Since the sql statement required another set of quotes i just added them to ensure it was treated as its own string.