# string.format quotes escaping in variables

Tags: python-3.x, string, format

I have an issue when I am trying to retrieve data from a postgres database using psycopg2 cursor.
I am using a string.format to pass my variable name in the cursor query, but whenever the name contains a single quote, the quote won't be escaped and an error will be raised.

Here is my python code :

```
def getFirstOrderDate(exact_hotel_name):

    ## Retrieve the first order date to know how old is the property ##

    con=psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname(),host=host(),port=port(),user=user(),password=password())
    cur=con.cursor()
    firstOrderTxt="Select hotel_name,exact_hotel_name,min(order_date) from fact.podio_orders where exact_hotel_name = '{}' group by hotel_name,exact_hotel_name".format(str(exact_hotel_name))
    cur.execute(firstOrderTxt)
    firstOrder=cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    return firstOrder[0][2]
```

And it raised this error, which is obviously logic, but I don't succeed to find a solution:
[image]

I tried to modify firstOrderTxt by this `firstOrderTxt='Select hotel_name,exact_hotel_name,min(order_date) from fact.podio_orders where exact_hotel_name = "{}" group by hotel_name,exact_hotel_name'.format(exact_hotel_name)` 
but I am getting this error, where I don't understand why my variable name is looked for as a column of the table:
[image]

Can you help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128973/235698. Using `.format` allows SQL injection attacks.  Use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `.format` in SQL statements unless you REALLY have a good reason to. **ESPECIALLY with user input!**. They are very easy to SQLI (unless you really want to go through every single escape/check/replace individually). Below is an example of what you are doing, vs what you should do rather than using `.format`:

Incorrect:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM x WHERE y = {}".format("customer"))
```

Correct:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM x WHERE y = %s", ["customer"])
```