# How to create a database with psycopg2 using execute() second argument?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a database with the name a user will provide. As far as I know the correct way is to use the second argument of [execute()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters).

So I did as follows:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="...", dbname="...",
                        user="...", password="...", port='...')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = ''' CREATE DATABASE %s ;'''
name = 'stackoverflow_example_db'

conn.autocommit = True
cursor.execute(query, (name,))

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

And I got this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'stackoverflow_example_db'"
LINE 1:  CREATE DATABASE 'stackoverflow_example_db' ;
```

I need to do this statement avoiding SQL injection, so using the second argument is a must.

Comment: Why would you let users create databases?

Comment: @dfundako it's for users with administration privileges, who do not necessary have to know SQL for the app purpose.

Comment: Related: [Passing table name as a parameter in psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13793399/190597). Although the discussion is about tables, the answer is essentially the same for database names. See in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947632/190597) which uses [pyscopg2.sql.SQL](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) and [Identifier](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier)s to build the SQL dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Postgres database using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484066/create-a-postgres-database-using-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass values as [second argument](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters) of execute(), if the statement is a CREATE DATABASE one.

As pointed out by [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776043/how-to-create-a-database-with-psycopg2#comment101987519_57776043) one way to approach this is using the [psycopg2.sql](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) submodule and use [identifiers](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier) to build the statement [avoiding SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45236961/11824299).

The code:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="...", dbname="...",
                        user="...", password="...", port='...')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = ''' CREATE DATABASE {} ;'''
name = 'stackoverflow_example_db'

conn.autocommit = True
cursor.execute(sql.SQL(query).format(
    sql.Identifier(name)))

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Other aditional observations:

- format() do not work with %s, use {} instead
- Autocommit mode is a must for this statement to work
- The specified connection user needs creation privileges