# How do you pass json to a parameterized sql statement using psycopg2?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2, jsonb

---

- What's the correct syntax to pass json into a parameterized SQL statement?
- How do you safely pass a variable into the json along with it?

---

I have a table with a field called `properties` that is typed as a `jsonb`. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  ...snip...
  properties jsonb
)
```

I can query it in pgAdmin as follows:

```
SELECT id from mytable where properties@>'{"favorites": [{"icecream": "vanilla"}]}';
```

Now I would like to do it with psycopg2, but I would like to parameterize it.

Normally, this can be done like so:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id from mytable where something = (%s)", (123456))
```

**How do you do it with a jsonb?  And then how do you parameterize the flavor of ice cream?**

Here's how far I've gotten so far.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import register_default_jsonb, register_default_json, Json

...snip...

register_default_jsonb()
register_default_json()

def who_likes_this_icecream(flavor):
    #where_clause = '{"favorites": [{"icecream": "vanilla"}]}'
    where_clause = Json({"favorites": [{"icecream": "vanilla"}]})
    q = "SELECT id from mytable where properties @> (%s)"

    with get_a_cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(q, (where_clause))
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        r = cursor.fetchone()
        return r[0]['id']


id = who_likes_this_icecream('vanilla')
print (id)
```

I tried using the Json wrapper in psycopg2 and received:

`TypeError: 'Json' object does not support indexing`

I tried sending the JSON in as a formatted string and received:

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Also, I am not sure how to safely send in the variable `flavor` without introducing an injection issue.

[Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793399/passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-psycopg2)

Comment: I don't think the parentheses in your SQL are necessary; `"SELECT id from ... where properties @> %s"`.

Comment: `cursor.execute(q, (where_clause,))` - comma after `where_clause`.

Comment: Doh. I see it. The comma after, makes it a tuple. Thanks @Abelisto

Comment: How about parameterizing the flavor of icecream so as to avoid some kind of injection attack.  Is it possible with JSON?  Any examples?

Comment: Using parametrized `cursor.execute()` protects you against SQL injection.

Comment: So just doing a string replacement on the JSON where clause is enough?