# SQL Query in Python (psycopg2) SyntaxError

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error, psycopg2

Code where the error appears:

```
def isID_inTable(id,table='question'):
   cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM %s;' , [table])
```

Error message:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'question'"

LINE 1: SELECT id FROM 'question';
```

Comment: (table,) not [table]

Comment: Same result with (table,). Same with double quotes.

Comment: `sql = 'SELECT id FROM {};' . format(table)
   cursor.execute(sql)`

Comment: I will check in a moment. but i heard its not a best practice in case of sql injection

Comment: Still same result

Comment: Do you use PostgreSQL? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: PostgreSQL_____

Comment: related, possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793399/passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-psycopg2

Answer (score -1):

You need a where clause for the query to execute

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE condition
```

Comment: what if they want all records, i.e. no condition? :-)

Comment: Also use triple parenthesis """ if you are writing multi-line queries

Comment: I did triple parenthesis, no difference

Comment: This is absolutely untrue.  You can have a select statement without a where clause.