# psycopg2 table name as a parameter fails with double quotes

Tags: parameters, psycopg2

I use this python function to get column names from different tables in postGres.

```
def get_table_columns(conn, table):
"""
Retrieve a list of column names in a table
:param conn:
:param table:
:return: List of column names
"""
try:
    query = sql.SQL('SELECT * FROM {} LIMIT 0').format(sql.Identifier(table))
    print(query.as_string(conn))
    with conn as c:
        with c.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(query)
            return [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

except psycopg2.DatabaseError as de:
    logger.error("DatabaseError in get_table_columns: {0}".format(str(de)))
    raise de
except Exception as ex:
    logger.error("Exception in get_table_columns: {0}".format(str(ex)))
    raise ex
```

I'm receiving error, "relation "v43fs.evt_event_cycle" does not exist.

The print statement looks like this:
SELECT * FROM "v43fs.evt_event_cycle" LIMIT 0

The double quotes are causing the query to fail. How can I make them go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the query to be formatted as follows and it works much better now:

```
query = sql.SQL('SELECT * FROM {}.{} LIMIT 0').format(sql.Identifier(schema), sql.Identifier(table))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder if this should be made more explicit in the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql).