# Unable to Pass in Table Name for Query psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to pass in the table name for my queries but it doesn't work when I use the code below.

```
def retrieve_data_single(table_name, date):
    
    
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", port = 5432, database="db", user="user")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    date = date + "%"
    
    cur.execute("""SELECT open, date FROM table_name WHERE date LIKE (%s)""" , [date])

retrieve_data_single(table_1, '2022-12-12'):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:

[Passing table name as a parameter in psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793399/passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-psycopg2)

You should be using this

template:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
cur.execute(
    sql.SQL("insert into {table} values (%s, %s)")
        .format(table=sql.Identifier('my_table')), # table name here
    [10, 20]) ## other parameters here
```