# postgresql sanitize parameter with no simple quote

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm working on postgresql and doing security check about SQL injection. I'm refactoring my code to avoid SQL injection.

I want to do the average of a column named "television"
Here my code :

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
   sql.append(
        f"""SELECT COUNT(*),
              AVG(%s)
              FROM dataset"""
    )
    values.append(target)

    cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

If i print values:

```
['television']
```

But i got error :

```
LINE 3:      AVG('television'),
```

It's look like simple quote are problem here, i need to have AVG("television").
There is a way to force simple quote to double quote ?

I tried to parameter it before like that :

```
new_target = f'"{target}"'
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql.append(
        f"""SELECT COUNT(*),
              AVG(%s)
              FROM dataset"""
    )
    values.append(new_target)

    cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

But got almost same error:

```
AVG('"television"'),
```

Comment: We can't parameterize the column names in the SQL string. Either you have to construct the SQL string by concatenation or keep a placeholder and replace it with the table name. I prefer/follow the 2nd one.

Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement

Comment: Near-duplicate, if you’re using psycopg2 (it’s about a table name, not a column name, but the same solutions apply): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793399/passing-table-name-as-a-parameter-in-psycopg2/42947632#42947632