# PostgreSQL Schema "www" does not exist?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

From the PostgreSQL documentation if you do a INSERT without specifying a schema it should be a *public* schema.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'orion',
                host = 'localhost',
                port = 5432,
                user = 'earthling',
                password = 'mysupersecretpassword') 
sql = conn.cursor()

def INSERT(table, info, text):
    date = datetime.date.today()
    query = "INSERT INTO %s (info, text, date) " \
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" %(table, info, text, date)
    sql.execute(query)

INSERT("main", "www.capecod.edu", "test")
```

For some reason I'm seeing the following error?

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: schema "www" does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using string interpolation to create the query. This is what psycopg2 executes:

```
INSERT INTO main (info, text, date)
    VALUES (www.capecod.edu, test, 2015-09-12)
```

If it's not obvious what's wrong here, it's that none of the values are quoted. Here is the properly quoted version:

```
INSERT INTO main (info, text, date)
    VALUES ('www.capecod.edu', 'test', '2015-09-12')
```

The error is caused by the unquoted `www.capecod.edu`. Due to the dots, it's being interpreted as `schema.table.column`.

The "right" way to do this is with a parameterized query.

```
query = "INSERT INTO main (info, text, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
params = (info, text, date)
sql.execute(query, params)
```

psycopg2 will figure out what should be quoted and how. This is a safer option than simply interpolating the string yourself, which often leaves you open to SQL injection attack.

http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2012/10/01/prepared-statements-psycopg/

Unfortunately, you can't just toss identifiers such as the table name in as a parameter, because then they are quoted as string values, which is bad SQL syntax. I found an answer ([python adds "E" to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382234/python-adds-e-to-string/13891511#13891511)) that points to `psycopg2.extensions.AsIs` as a way to pass identifiers such as table names safely as parameters. I wasn't able to make this work in my testing, though.

If you go the `AsIs` route, you should be cautious about checking the table names are valid, if they somehow come from user input. Something like

```
valid_tables = ["main", "foo", "bar", "baz"]

if table not in valid_tables:
    return False
```

Comment: This won't work as written. You must interpolate the string yourself, because psycopg2 doesn't know it's an identifier not a literal.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks, I hadn't caught that. You can pass the table name in as a param actually, you just have to be more cautious... I will edit the answer.

Comment: After adding the '' around the name it seems to be working only I didn't see the entry in my table?  Is this because I need to use params ALWAYS?? Or maybe the date needs to be of PostgreSQL style not python style?

Comment: Using params is optional, but encouraged if the data comes from user input (to avoid SQL injection attacks). I can't say more without seeing what you actually did - where did you put the quotes? What is your new code? Please update the question with the new details...

Comment: Its kinda odd I'm doing a INSERT("main", "www.whoi.edu", "test")
print SELECT("main", "www.whoi.edu") and I get NONE.  My query = "INSERT INTO %s (url, text, date) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')" %(table, url, text, date)

Comment: I added the "" around and there seems to be something else... maybe on the DB side since I don't see it.

Comment: Using double-quote for strings in a SQL query won't work, you need single-quotes. To SQL, `"main"` is not the same thing as `'main'`. Also you're still using string interpolation, so without extra validation effort, you are still going to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.