# Insert query with variables postgresql python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert several variables in a insert query on postgres using python. I can't wrap my head around how to use the string formatting.

For example, this works fine:

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE %s 
 (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 sender varchar(255) not null,
 receiver varchar(255) not null,
 message varchar(255))''' %username)
```

as does this:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO test (sender, receiver, message)             
VALUES(%s,%s,%s)''', (sender, receiver,message))
```

My problem is that I want to have the table name as a variable too. I have tried:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO %s (sender, receiver, message)
VALUES(%s,%s,%s)''' %username, (sender, receiver, message))
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

I get that I have to change the parentheses somehow, but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Choose a different approach from this [psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475309/psycopg-error-column-does-not-exist) which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the arguments in a wrong way. The arguments passed are causing you the trouble. Use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) function instead of % as it is more sophisticated and readable.

```
"INSERT INTO {} (sender, receiver, message) VALUES({},{},{})".format("some", "world", "world","hello")
```

The output of the above:

```
'INSERT INTO some (sender, receiver, message) VALUES(world,world,hello)'
```

Comment: with:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {} (sender, receiver, message)
    VALUES({},{},{}).format(username, "one", "two", "three"))



I got:
>psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "one" does not exist
LINE 1: ...SERT INTO test (sender, receiver, message) VALUES(one,two,th...

Comment: See my response above

Comment: @LudvigKnutsmark Your error is from a wrong query but string is formatted correctly. Check that table you are inserting in does exists and column names are correct. If you are having another error then ask a new question.

Comment: Hello. I think this approach would be prone to SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

Use the high level [`sql` module](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) to avoid likely mistakes:

```
from psycopg2 import sql

query = sql.SQL('''
    insert into {} (sender, receiver, message)
    values (%s, %s, %s)
''').format(sql.Identifier(username))

cursor.execute (query, (sender, receiver, message))
```