# postgres dblink escape single quote

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping, dblink

Related Link:

- [String literals and escape characters in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935/string-literals-and-escape-characters-in-postgresql)

Here is my error:

```
ERROR:  type "e" does not exist
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dblink('host=theHostName port=1234 dbname=theDBName user=theUser password=thePassword',
    E'SELECT field_1, 
    CASE WHEN field_2 IS NOT NULL 
    THEN \'inactive\' ELSE \'active\' 
    END AS field_status 
    FROM the_table 
     ') 
AS linkresults(field_1 varchar(20),field_2 varchar(8))
```

If I use double quotes, remove the backslash escape for the single quotes and remove the E before the SELECT statement

```
SELECT *
FROM dblink('host=theHostName port=1234 dbname=theDBName user=theUser password=thePassword',
    "SELECT field_1, 
    CASE WHEN field_2 IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 'inactive' ELSE 'active' 
    END AS field_status 
    FROM the_table 
     ") 
AS linkresults(field_1 varchar(20),field_2 varchar(8))
```

I get this:

```
NOTICE:  identifier "SELECT ..." will be truncated
```

And the I also get the ERROR as my query has been truncated.

I have escaped with dblink like this before, so is there a server setting or something I need to configure?

I know the query works just fine if I run it on the sql server itself, but not with dblink. Any thoughts?

Postgres version 8.4

Comment: @niktrs your post worked, why delete it?

Comment: I have updated it to something more simple. If it doesn't work I can report the previous answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try replacing `\'inactive\'` with `''inactive''` -- caution: two single quotes

```
   SELECT *
    FROM dblink('host=theHostName port=1234 dbname=theDBName user=theUser password=thePassword',
        'SELECT field_1, 
        CASE WHEN field_2 IS NOT NULL 
        THEN ''inactive'' ELSE ''active'' 
        END AS field_status 
        FROM the_table 
         ') 

AS linkresults(field_1 varchar(20),field_2 varchar(8))
```

Alternative (previous) solution

```
   SELECT *
    FROM dblink('host=theHostName port=1234 dbname=theDBName user=theUser password=thePassword',
        'SELECT field_1, 
        CASE WHEN field_2 IS NOT NULL 
        THEN E\'inactive\' ELSE E\'active\' 
        END AS field_status 
        FROM the_table 
         ') 

AS linkresults(field_1 varchar(20),field_2 varchar(8))
```

Comment: Tell me if alternative also works. Would like to know since I don't have postgre installed in my pc.

Comment: E\'inactive\' this worked for me as well your other solution using the two single quotes ''

Comment: You can also use $$ style quotes.

Answer (score 6):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
 FROM dblink('host=theHostName port=1234 dbname=theDBName user=theUser password=thePassword',
 'SELECT field_1, 
 CASE WHEN field_2 IS NOT NULL 
 THEN $$inactive$$ ELSE $$active$$ 
 END AS field_status 
 FROM the_table') 
 AS linkresults(field_1 varchar(20),field_2 varchar(8))
```

Comment: Giving a bit more context and using a code block would improve this answer.