# Running a postgres query between two databases with conditions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, dblink

I have two postgres databases on a single server.

I need to extract records from one database and put them into another. This is my **working** query.

```
insert into "tblInvInfo"
select "iiInvNum", "iiItemCode","iiUnitMeasure", "iiUnitQuantity", 
"iiPrice", "iiUnits" from 
 dblink ('dbname=dbESM', 'SELECT * from "tblInvInfo" ')
    AS invinfo ("iiInvNum" varchar, "iiItemCode" varchar, 
    "iiItemName" varchar, "iiUnitMeasure" varchar, "iiUnitQuantity" numeric, 
    "iiPrice" numeric, "iiUnits" numeric)
```

Basically, this pulls the records from **tblInvInfo** of **dbESM** and puts them in the identical table of **dbESMTemp**

Now, to the requirement... **tblInvMaster** contains the main details of an invoice (and includes the date), while **tblInvInfo** has the details of items.

I need to only extract records from **tblInvInfo** that match specific conditions in **tblInvMaster**. I presume this is done through a simple inner join query. So this is what I tried:

```
insert into "tblInvInfo"
select "iiInvNum", "iiItemCode","iiUnitMeasure", 
"iiUnitQuantity", "iiPrice", "iiUnits" from 
 dblink ('dbname=dbESM', 'SELECT "iiInvNum", "iiItemCode",
 "iiUnitMeasure", "iiUnitQuantity", "iiPrice", "iiUnits" from 
 (select "tblInvInfo".* from (select * from "tblInvMaster" 
 where "invDate" between \'2014-08-01\' and \'2014-10-17\') invmaster 
 inner join "tblInvInfo" on "invInvNum" = "iiInvNum"  ) filteredinvinfo ')
    AS invinfo ("iiInvNum" varchar, "iiItemCode" varchar,
     "iiItemName" varchar, "iiUnitMeasure" varchar, 
     "iiUnitQuantity" numeric, "iiPrice" numeric, "iiUnits" numeric);
```

For the above query, I get the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2014" LINE 7:  where "invDate"
>   between \'2014-08-01\' and \'2014-10-17\') ...
>                                      ^

My join is correct but I have three areas of doubt regarding the query:

1. Is it correct, the way in which the codition is given?
2. Is the escaping technique used (back-slash) in the query correct?
3. I'm not sure how to specify the column names to extract using this **dblink** function.

Any help in getting this solved is truly appreciated.

Comment: You escape quotes with another quote in dblink, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615732/postgres-dblink-escape-single-quote

Comment: Also, you might want to look at [foreign data wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html) instead of dblink. I haven't played with them much, but they are considered a more modern approach than dblink.

Comment: Thanks John, but I think I'll stick to dblink for its simplicity and limited use in my case.