# How to escape binary data for insertion into PostgreSQL database with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql

I'm trying to insert binary data (`QImage`) into a PostgreSQL 8.4.9 `bytea` column from Qt 4.8.
My code looks like this:

```
QImage image;
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // Save the QImage data into the QBuffer

QSqlQuery query = QSqlQuery(database);
query.prepare("INSERT INTO images (image) "
              "VALUES (:image)");

query.bindValue(":image", ba);
query.exec();
qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
```

This works, but I get the following error:

> WARNING:  nonstandard use of \ in a string literal LINE 1: ...XECUTE
>   qpsqlpstmt_1 ('\211PNG... HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for
>   backslashes, e.g., E'\'

How can I escape the data properly to avoid this warning?

**EDIT :**

Here is some essential information regarding this topic:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-binary.html

The way I see it, each byte should be surrounded by `E''::bytea` before passing to `bindValue`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do by supplying a binary data where a column name should go (the first mention of `:image` in your INSERT statement).

Comment: That was just a typo. I cleaned columns not related to this problem from the code to make the question more general.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [docs](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#bindValue) for `.bindValue` - you most probably need to [indicate](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsql.html#ParamTypeFlag-enum) that the value is binary:

```
query.bindValue(":image", ba, QSql::In | QSql::Binary);
```

Comment: This doesn't have any effect. And I believe it should be `QSql::In | QSql::Binary`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the E'' around your QByteArray? I don't know if that will work for an image but it seems to work for strings.

[String literals and escape characters in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935/string-literals-and-escape-characters-in-postgresql)