# Export text content to text file without \n mark

Tags: postgresql

When I try to export the text content of a field, and that content have carriage return characters, that chars are output like \N string.

For example:

```
create table foo ( txt text );
insert into foo ( txt ) values ( 'first line
second line
...
and other lines');
copy foo ( txt ) to '/tmp/foo.txt';
```

I want to return the following (a):

```
first line
second line
...
and other lines
```

But, output is (b):

```
first line\Nsecond line\N...\Nand other lines
```

Anybody knows how to get the (a) output?

Comment: What did you find when you searched around?

Answer (score 6):

The `\N` comes from the fact that one line must correspond to one database row.

This rule is relaxed for the CSV format where multi-line text is possible but then a quote character (by default: `"`) would enclose the text.

If you want multi-line output and no enclosing character around it, you shouldn't use `COPY`  but `SELECT`.

Assuming a unix shell as the execution environment of the caller, you could do:

```
psql -A -t -d dbname -c 'select txt from foo' >/tmp/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `\r\n`?

Here's another solution that might work:

```
E'This is the first part \\n And this is the second'
```

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/938/1085891

Also, rather than copy the other responses, see here: [String literals and escape characters in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935/string-literals-and-escape-characters-in-postgresql)