# PostgreSQL: nonstandard use of escape string

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 8.4 database that is being queried by an application that is outside of my control.  Queries such as the following are throwing warnings but are working...

```
SELECT "tagname","tagindex","tagtype","tagdatatype"  FROM "tagtable" WHERE "tagname" = 'Lift_Stations\07\ETMs\Generator_ETM'
```

However, the same query for stations 08 and 09 are failing...

```
SELECT "tagname","tagindex","tagtype","tagdatatype"  FROM "tagtable" WHERE "tagname" = 'Lift_Stations\08\ETMs\Generator_ETM'
```

> WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal LINE 2:
>   ...,"tagdatatype"  FROM "tagtable" WHERE "tagname" = 'Lift_Stat...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
>
> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00 HINT:  This
>   error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding
>   expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
>
> *** *Error* *****
>
> ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00 SQL state:
>   22021 Hint: This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not
>   match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by
>   "client_encoding".

I know the problem is incorrect escaping, but given the fact that 08 and 09 are the only ones not working, I'm hoping someone might have a bright idea on how to work around this.

Thanks!

Comment: `WHERE "tagname" = E'Lift_Stations\08\ETMs\Generator_ETM'` could help.

Comment: If do not work wildplasser's solution, please try add another backslashes, for more information read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/943/1563878).

Comment: @wildplasser I think that's a path, and they don't *want* it to be interpreted as escape sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you [enable `standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html).

Comment: To elaborate on this correct but brief answer: Older PostgreSQL versions used to let you write C-style escapes like `\n` in strings. This has been turned off by default in newer versions; this warning tells you that you're on a version where it still happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help @CraigRinger, always nice to see another 2ndQ member here ;)

Comment: I didn't realise you were on the team. Stealthy. Amsterdam... wonder who that could be ;-) . Really supposed to have mention of 2ndQ in your profile if doing Pg related community stuff IIRC.

Comment: Yes... I suppose I should really write a little bio ;)