# Postgres SQL Single quote Escape

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho

I need a help in escaping single quotes in postgresql insert. I am using a ETL tool for data extraction from source and loading in a postgresql database.The Select statement includes some variables.

For example  My select query is

```
SELECT ${UNIVERSITY},date from education.
```

The variable `${UNIVERSITY}` has the value `Duke's university`. This statement gives me an error

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
```

and not getting loaded into the postgres table. Could anyone help me in esacping the single quote and how should I use in variables?

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935/string-literals-and-escape-characters-in-postgresql) helps ?

Comment: You can escape single quotes in Postgres by using `''`.  See [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql) for more information.

Comment: Are you executing the query from Pentaho Spoon or Pentaho report designer?

Comment: I am executing the query from Pentaho spoon.

Comment: does the ${UNIVERSITY} really refers to a column in education table or is is just a value you want to add to the result? if its not a table column I can give you a solution from spoon

Comment: Just a value . I am getting this values from GET and SET variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `SELECT REPLACE(${UNIVERSITY},'''', ''''''),date from education.`
But probably you just need to do `SELECT '${UNIVERSITY}',date from education` as your query looks like:

```
SELECT Duke's university,date from education
```

That is definitely wrong by SQL syntax.

Comment: Could you please explain on using multiple quotes here. why do we use ''''  (4 quotes) here. Thanks

Comment: the syntax of REPLACE is REPLACE(whatTochange,stringToFind,StringToChange); in most cases it looks like REPLACE('someetext','ee', 'e'); So, here you have to single quotes already. Now you need to find single quote '. Escaped it looks like ''. If you put that into single quotes, then you have '''' already. The next step is to change it to double quote. Double escaped quote is '''' and if you put that to the single quotes, then you have 6 single quotes already :) But as I said, that check the 2nd option.

Comment: you can use advanced quoting that postgres offers: select '''' is the same as select $'$ and select e'\''... this is much more clear than oracle '''' way...

Comment: @VaoTsun it is not Oracle way. It is standard ANSI way.

Comment: @sidux Cool! my accent was - Postgres lets you to use other quoting, which a lot of people find easier to read :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have mentioned it does not refer a column in the table education. You can achieve the same expected output through this transformation.
[image]

Here in 
 - `Table input` step you can write the query `SELECT date from education`  
 -  In `split fields` step you can add a new column to your result as `University` 

 - From `Get Variables` step you can assign the parameter values to the new column University  
 -Obtain the result in `Select Values` step

Answer (score 3):

@Marlon Abeykoon's answer is very good. You can also do it this way.

[image]

Put this in a job and set a parameter or variable there called `UNIVERSITY` and give it the "Duke's University" value. Launch the above transform from there. The pick a join condition that always results in true. I used 'yr_key IS NOT NULL'. The following is the result:

[image]

Then you can just run the results into a `Table Output` step to load into PostgreSQL.