# Why does my postgresql SELECT statement return 0 rows?

Tags: postgresql, select

Maybe I'm missing something painfully obvious but I'm trying to select from a table with a column called 'email' with type character(50).

I set up a simple test and i can successfully query every other column except for this one. For now the columns 'name' and 'password' are also of type character(50);

I'm copying and pasting the sample email 'johnsmith@gmail.com' exactly as is listed in the database and I am sure there are no extra spaces.

Here is my table called 'users':

```
id | name |        email        | password
---------------------------------------------
10 | john | johnsmith@gmail.com | adsfpokasdf
```

My query is:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = 'johnsmith@gmail.com';
```

Is there a problem with my choice of the column type?

Here is a picture:
[Why is this postgresql SELECT statement returning 0 rows?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPLN6.png)

Comment: may be you have a leading or trailing whitespace in the email? what does `select email from users` return?

Comment: Another way to test [the suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217565/why-does-my-postgresql-select-statement-return-0-rows#comment61966342_37217565) is to use `trim()` function: `WHERE trim(email) = 'johnsmith@gmail.com'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe I'm missing something painfully obvious but I'm trying to select from a table with a column called 'email' with type character(50).

This is your issue. You want the type `character varying` (also known as `varchar`. The `text` type will work just as well, without a length check). `character(50)` will only hold strings of length 50, and will pad it with spaces to fill that out.

Re-create the table with the column types as `varchar(50)` or `text`, and try again. It should work closer to expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my where clause from

```
SELECT "fieldId" FROM MyTable WHERE 'fieldId' = 'stringid'
```

to

```
SELECT "fieldId" FROM MyTable WHERE "fieldId" = 'stringid'
```

Basically the single quotes in the where clause to double. I am not sure why I have to quote it, but in some instances of postgres I have had to do this.

Hopefully this helps someone else :)

Comment: "*why I have to quote it*": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS  Additionally: `'fieldId'` is a string constant in SQL, not a column name: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score -2):

Maybe '@' is used for pattern-matching in PostgreSQL?  If so, it might need the escape character preceeding it...

TRY:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = 'johnsmith\@gmail.com';
```

Also try (from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935/string-literals-and-escape-characters-in-postgresql) post):

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = E'johnsmith@gmail.com';
```

Lastly:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = E'johnsmith\@gmail.com';
```

Comment: Good thought - I gave this a try and it still didn't work. I deleted the original row, created it again with the same info, and when I queried for it again it worked. There must have been some character discrepancy that I'm not seeing.

Thanks so much for your quick reply.