# How to grant permissions for user with '-' in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping

I want to permissions to a user named foo-bar in PostgreSQL (the key is that the username has a minus '-' in it). However, when I use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE baz TO foo-bar`, postgres complains about the minus character being invalid syntax. I figured that made sense, I just needed to use a string literal or escape the minus. However, trying the double dollar sign literal [syntax here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) and prepending an `E` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935/string-literals-and-escape-characters-in-postgresql) didn't work (presumably because the username isn't considered a string here).

So that begs the question, how *does* one refer to a user in postgres if the user has a minus in their name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE baz TO "foo-bar"
```

should work

Comment: Well, now I feel silly. I tried single quotes and it complained about that, but apparently forgot double quotes.