Liquibase unable to insert data that contains $$ using loadUpdateData
I am trying to read data from csv using Liquibase and naturally trying to use loadUpdateData. My csv has title column which is varchar
The data for some records contains $$ and those records give an error while inserting using liquibase. When I checked the query in logs it showed below:
DO
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE public.ted_talk SET author = ' Yelle', date = 'June 2018', likes = 7700, link = 'https://ted.com/talks/yelle_interpassion_ba_in', views = 259000 WHERE title = '"Interpassion" / "Ba$$in"';
IF not found THEN
INSERT INTO public.ted_talk (title, author, date, views, likes, link) VALUES ('"Interpassion" / "Ba$$in"', ' Yelle', 'June 2018', 259000, 7700, 'https://ted.com/talks/yelle_interpassion_ba_in');
END IF;
END;
$$

As you are aware, $$ is defined as delimiter to include blocks of code and if the data contains $$ it is unable to parse it. How can I escape the $$ so that liquibase detects the correct string and stores in DB.
I tried using escape character like \ but that did not help.
Referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935/string-literals-and-escape-characters-in-postgresql and was able to add E in the beginning and execute it successfully in DB directly.
But how can I put this in liquibase?

The documentation says:

A dollar-quoted string constant consists of a dollar sign ($), an optional “tag” of zero or more characters, another dollar sign, an arbitrary sequence of characters that makes up the string content, a dollar sign, the same tag that began this dollar quote, and a dollar sign.

So you could use for example
DO
$abc$
BEGIN
   UPDATE public.ted_talk SET ... WHERE title = '"Interpassion" / "Ba$$in"';
   ...
END;
$abc$;

